# iOS 9 universal links working. Exclusion path not working

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-universal-links

There are several other posts which say universal links are not working. I have a different issue where these links are working, however I want to exclude some specific url's on my website from launching the app and this is not working.

As documented here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

I have implemented the necessary steps for universal link including uploading the apple-app-site-association file.

The file looks like this example:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
        {
            "appID": "AB1CDEFGHI.com.mydomain.myapp",
            "paths": [ "*", "NOT /help/" ]
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

The intention here is if a user clicks www.mydomain.com/help it will not launch the app but open this page in safari. However this link opens the app.

I have tried several versions of this path including:

```
/help/* 
/help/
/help
help
```

none of these provide the desired exclusion functionality.

Has anybody been able to implement this type of exclusion?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, by changing:

```
[ "*", "NOT /help/" ]
```

to:

```
[ "NOT /help/", "*" ]
```

It worked as expected. The order of the paths matters and by putting "*" first the system will find a match on the first path and will launch the app.

Simple enough...

Answer (score 0):

You should use "NOT /help/" having the NOT inside the string.

Also, I suggest you look at AppsFlyer's solution for Universal Links. It may be a good alternative (using another applinks path).

Comment: Thanks, if this was the solution that would be great. Unfortunately my post was incorrect as I was already using "NOT /help/". I have edited my post to reflect this.